# Button Click in JavaScript to add a row in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My task is to make a page with a table and a button. When the user presses a button, one row is added to the table.
So, I have a button on my html page ( `<button id="my_button">Bla-bla</button>` ),
and a table (  `<table id="my_table">` ). And I have a separate file for JavaScript. In that file I wrote:

```
$(function() {
    $(my_button).click(function(){            
       tbl = document.getElementById("my_table");
       row = tbl.insertRow(0);      
       var newCell = row.insertCell(0);
       newCell.height=300;
       newCell.innerHTML="Some New Text";
    });
});
```

But there is a problem: when I press the button, the row is added for several milliseconds, then it vanishes and I see the table without the new row again.
What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Is there any other code on the page that uses `setTimeout` or the like?

Comment: Do you have any other Javascript that could be conflicting with this? On it's own it appears to work as intended ([Example](http://jsbin.com/ekikam/1/edit))

Comment: Probably nothing to do with your problem, but why not use `$('#my_table')` and `$('#my_table').append()`?

Comment: Have you tried http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_table_insertrow

Comment: You're probably submitting a `form` when you click the button, so the page refreshes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here a small example

html code

```
<table class="authors-list">
    <tr>
        <td>author's first name</td><td>author's last name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<a href="#" title="" class="add-author">Add Author</a>
```

jquery code

```
var counter = 1;
jQuery('a.add-author').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" name="first_name' +
        counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="last_name' +
        counter + '"/></td></tr>');
    jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);
});
```

see this link for working this code
http://jsfiddle.net/yUfhL/

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use jQuery for the click event you might as well use it consistently in your code.

Give this a whirl: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uX6Zq/1/)

```
$("#my_button").click(function(){            
    $("#my_table").append('<tr style="height:300px"><td>Some New text</td></tr>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your mark up it could be as the system's comment suggested that the form is submitting and the page is refreshing.

If this is the case, the simple solution is to use the event.preventDefault() in your handler:

```
$(function() {
    $(my_button).click(function(){ 
        event.preventDefault();           
        tbl = document.getElementById("my_table");
        row = tbl.insertRow(0);      
        var newCell = row.insertCell(0);
        newCell.height=300;
        newCell.innerHTML="Some New Text";
   });
```

});

You ca read more about the preventDefault in the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

As per other answers, if you have access to jquery, you can tidy up the method by using it throughout the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
          $(document).ready(function(){        
               $(document).on("click","td.addNewButton",function(e) {   
                     var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());   
                     var html = $('#myTable tbody tr:eq('+row+')').html();   
                     $('#myTable tbody tr:eq('+row+')').after('<tr>'+html+'</tr>');  
               }); 
         }); 
    </script>
```

This will do nicely for you :)